# Detect template driven form change from the component

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a template-driven form

```
<form #form="ngForm">
  ...
</form>
```

I need to detect if form becomes dirty in component.ts file.

I know I can access form using @ViewChild in the component

```
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm;
```

Using `this.myForm.statusChanges` only gives me form status (VALID, INVALID etc), and it doesn't say if the form became dirty. `this.myForm.valueChanges` only gives new values that were entered in the form, and doesn't specify if form is pristine or dirty.

Is there an easy way to access dirty state of a template-driven form in the component, when form changes? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you're already being notified if the status changes, which will be triggered anytime a form input's value is changed. So there's no reason you cannot use that to check to see if the form is dirty, since when the form does become dirty, it will result in statusChanges being fired:

```
  @ViewChild(NgForm) form: NgForm;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form.statusChanges.subscribe(() => {
      console.log("Is form dirty yet: " + this.form.dirty);
    });
```

As soon as the form becomes dirty, the subscription will be fired.

Comment: use `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`.  `ngOnInit` would return undefined since the view is not initialised yet.

Answer (score -4):

Use reactive forms. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms. You will be able to create a FormGroup and control form's state.

Comment: If someone's got a problem with their car, isn't it better to help them with that instead of suggesting to buy another brand? ;-)

Comment: I know I can use Reactive Forms, but in my case it would require A LOT of refactoring. I need to get this working with Template-Driven forms